# Preserving aspect ratio in R's grid graphics

Tags: r, plot, r-grid

To draw a "crossed" rectangle of height 2 times larger than its width using the low-level `graphics` package facilities I call:

```
xlim <- c(0, 500)
ylim <- c(0, 1000)
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim, ylim, asp=1)
rect(xlim[1], ylim[1], xlim[2], ylim[2])
lines(c(xlim[1], xlim[2]), c(ylim[1], ylim[2]))
lines(c(xlim[1], xlim[2]), c(ylim[2], ylim[1]))
```

The figure has a nice feature: the aspect ratio is preserved so that if I change the size of the plot window, I get the same height-to-width proportions.

How can I obtain an equivalent result with `grid` graphics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a viewport that uses Square Normalised Parent Coordinates,
see `?unit`:

> *`"snpc"`: (...) This is useful for making things which are a proportion
>   of the viewport, but have to be square (or have a fixed aspect ratio).*

Here is the code:

```
library('grid')
xlim <- c(0, 500)
ylim <- c(0, 1000)
grid.newpage() # like plot.new()
pushViewport(viewport( # like plot.window()
        x=0.5, y=0.5, # a centered viewport
        width=unit(min(1,diff(xlim)/diff(ylim)), "snpc"), # aspect ratio preserved
        height=unit(min(1,diff(ylim)/diff(xlim)), "snpc"),
        xscale=xlim, # cf. xlim
        yscale=ylim  # cf. ylim
))
# some drawings:
grid.rect(xlim[1], ylim[1], xlim[2], ylim[2], just=c(0, 0), default.units="native")
grid.lines(xlim, ylim, default.units="native")
grid.lines(xlim, rev(ylim), default.units="native")
```

The `default.units` argument in e.g. `grid.rect` forces the plotting functions
to use the native (`xscale`/`yscale`) viewport coordinates.
`just=c(0, 0)` indicates that `xlim[1], ylim[1]` denote the bottom-left node
of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

In `ggplot2` (which is `grid` based) you can fix the aspect ratio using `coord_fixed()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + coord_fixed(ratio = 0.5)
```

This will fix the ratio, and the ratio will be constant even when changing the size of the graphics window.

I'm not sure if this is helpful, as you asked for a low-level `grid` based solution. But I thought it might be useful none the less.